# String consts/enums in typescript: const, namespace, or class?

Tags: typescript, enums, constants

We have an enum or a set of consts in our project, and a PR comment led to a discussion on what the most idiomatic way of structuring it is:

```
export class ThingTypes {
  public static readonly THING = "thing";
  public static readonly OTHERTHING = "otherthing";
}
```

or

```
export namespace ThingTypes {
  public static readonly THING = "thing";
  public static readonly OTHERTHING = "otherthing";
}
```

or

```
export const ThingTypes {
  THING: "thing",
  OTHERTHING: "otherthing"
}
```

We are not on >=2.4 so we cannot use `enum` (as prior to 2.4, they could only be strings), but for the sake of argument: would `enum` be the most idiomatic way? A la:

```
export enum ThingTypes {
  public static readonly THING = "thing";
  public static readonly OTHERTHING = "otherthing";
}
```

The internet is not yielding any clear answer. Which is the most idiomatic way and conventional way of making sets of consts in typescript?

Comment: Just using an `enum` isn't suitable?

Comment: Enums are limited to int values in ts.

Comment: What is the usage of the const value? Would the string value actually be used in some where or it just use for distinguishing the types?

Comment: @MikeManfrin starting ts2.4 those can be strings https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html

Comment: It's used to distinguish types within the same column on our db as well as included in apis for other consumers (so numbers aren't as helpful as strings).

Comment: Fair enough.  I personally have been using `type`s.  My API returns string values, so just having `type Things = 'Thing1' | 'Thing2'` works well for my situation.  Other than that, my inner full stack developer naturally leans towards your first option above, but realistically I'd probably go with whatever option compiles to smaller JS code, as they're all pretty similar syntactically.

Comment: Ahh @zerkms indeed they are -- that is nice to know. We are on an older version of TS so I think my original question is still applicable, but I'm going to edit it to account.